# I cant migrate, what shoud I do( laravel-5.8 ) ? SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

- 1.why cant I migrate ?

  ### I wanted to crate role permission table, but i cant add foreign key, i got this error :  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
- i tried to migrate, but got some errors
- i dont know what should i do in laravel 5.8

  ```
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateRoleAndPermissionTable extends Migration
  {
      /**
       * Run the migrations.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function up()
      {

          Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->increments('id');
              $table->string('name');
              $table->string('title')->nullable();
              $table->timestamps();
          });

          Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->increments('id');
              $table->string('name');
              $table->string('title')->nullable();
              $table->timestamps();
          });


          **Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
              $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

              $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
              $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

              $table->primary(['role_id','user_id']);

          });
  ```

---

### 2.it just migrate upper tables,It wont migrate this table ?

```
          Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {


                $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();


                $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
                $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

                 $table->primary(['permission_id','role_id']);  
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('role_and_permission');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment or remove all `$table->foreign('')` from all migration. It will work.

The best solution is to use `$table->bigIncrements('')` on `primary key` rather than `$table->increments('')` and `$table->unsignedBigInteger('');` for `foreign keys` rather than `$table->integer('');`.

Because `Laravel 5.8` uses `$table->bigIncrements('')` on `primary key` and `$table->unsignedBigInteger('');` for `foreign keys`.